# Nester.py: AttributeError: 'str' object has no value 'write'

Tags: python, list, module, attributeerror

Following the book, chapter four on persistence in Python, they ask us to amend the function of a module called "print_lol" inside of "nester".

Here's my code.

```
import sys 
def print_lol(the_list, indent=False, level=0, fh=sys.stdout):

    for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            print_lol(each_item, indent, level+1, fh) 
        else:
            if indent:
                for tab_stop in range(level):
                    print("\t", end='', file=fh)
            else:
                print(each_item, file=fh)
```

Here's the testing code.

```
import nester3

pl = nester3.print_lol

cat = ['death', [3, 4, 5, ['life']]]

pl(cat, indent=True, fh='amazing.txt')
```

What happens when I attempt to actually call this code is this statement:

```
File "tester.py", line 7, in <module>
    pl(cat, indent=True, fh='amazing.txt')
File "/home/ehl/Python/nester/nester3.py", line 39, in print_lol
    print_lol(each_item, indent, level+1, fh) 
File "/home/ehl/Python/nester/nester3.py", line 43, in print_lol
    print("\t", end='', file=fh)
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

I don't understand how I could possibly add the "write" attribute, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why have you added all those tags? Do you think there's anything linux-specific in here? Is there anything about lists or modules that's in any way relevant?

Comment: You're right. I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
with open('amazing.txt', 'a') as f:
    pl(cat, indent=True, fh=f)
```

You are currently trying to call `print(..., file='amazing.txt')` which tries to call `'amazing.txt'.write(...)` which of course does not make sense.

`'a'` opens file in append mode, you can use `'w'` to truncate and open in write mode.

Comment: you should use `'w'` mode here.

Comment: … or `a` or `r+`, if you don't want to truncate and overwrite any existing file.